# How to select fields as filter parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When the user clicks on the dropdownlist, the user can choose between start date or expiry date then types in the dates in the textboxes. The textboxes filter is working but **how do I get the dropdownlist to work so that the user can choose between start date and expiry date**.

[Date Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxeRY.png)

The part `FilterExpression= "'{0}' >= '{1}' AND '{0}' <= '{2}'">` in my sqldatasource is not working when I use `'{0}'` .

It's working when I do `FilterExpression= "start_date >= '{1}' AND start_date <= '{2}'">`  or `FilterExpression= "expiry_date >= '{1}' AND expiry_date <= '{2}'">`.

Note: *start_date* & *expiry_date* are fields from my table in database.

Dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Date_Type_DropDownList" runat="server" CssClass="custom-select dropdown-toggle ml-3" AutoPostBack="True">
      <asp:ListItem Text="Choose. . ." Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="Start Date" Value="start_date"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="Expiry Date" Value="expiry_date"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

SqlDataSource:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Gridview_SqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:databaseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM table" FilterExpression= "'{0}' >= '{1}' AND '{0}' <= '{2}'">
        <FilterParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Date_Type_DropDownList" Name="DateType" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="date_start_textbox" PropertyName="Text" DefaultValue="01/01/1900"/>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="date_end_textbox" PropertyName="Text" DefaultValue="31/12/3000" />
        </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: In `FilterExpression= "'{0}' >= '{1}' AND '{0}' <= '{2}'">` you're wrapping your column names in quotes, which will cause them to be treated as strings, not column names.

Comment: I see... So do you know what should I do to make the FilterExpression recognizes {0} as my column?